# Carriage position in input field (JavaScript)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have some issue with simple html input field, when I try to make some check with JS. I'm trying add some class and attribite depends on firt character, but if I'm trying to move carrege by arrows button it doesn't move.
May be some can help me and explain why it's happening.

Please find jsfiddle below
https://jsfiddle.net/4fpfjeed/

My JS file

```
jQuery(document).on('change keydown keyup click', ".js-format-login", function(event){
   var $self = jQuery(this),
       selfVal = $self.val();

   var c = selfVal.replace(/\s/gi, "");

   if(selfVal.indexOf('9643') === 0 || selfVal.indexOf('9642') === 0){
     $self.addClass('js-format-digits js-format-bonuscard').attr({
       'minlength': 19,
       'maxlength': 19,
       'data-min-symbols':"Min length is 16 character"
     });

   } else {
     $self.removeClass('js-format-digits js-format-bonuscard').attr({
       'minlength': 2,
    }).removeAttr('maxlength data-min-symbols').val(c);
   }
  });
```

Comment: just use the `input` event, not all those other ones.

Comment: @dandavis Thank you, it works fine for me!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you change the value of the input field, the cursor will be moved to the end.

You can prevent this by storing the position before you change the value, then change it back after you are done.

```
jQuery(document).on('change keydown keyup click', ".js-format-login", function(event) {
    var $self = jQuery(this),
        selfVal = $self.val();

    // store the cursor position //
    var start = this.selectionStart,
    var end = this.selectionEnd;
    ///////////////////////////////

    var c = selfVal.replace(/\s/gi, "");


    if (selfVal.indexOf('9643') === 0 || selfVal.indexOf('9642') === 0) {
        $self.addClass('js-format-digits js-format-bonuscard').attr({
            'minlength': 19,
            'maxlength': 19,
            'data-min-symbols': "Длина не менее 16 символов"
        });

    } else {
        $self.removeClass('js-format-digits js-format-bonuscard').attr({
            'minlength': 2,
        }).removeAttr('maxlength data-min-symbols').val(c);
    }

    //  set the position back //    
    this.setSelectionRange(start, end);
    ////////////////////////////

});
```